# facebook ad insights edge /ad_id/insights website_clicks vs link_clicks

Tags: api, ads, facebook-insights

I am using the ads api to retrieve statistics about an ad using the `/ad_id/insights` edge. Looking at the result fields I see the `link_clicks` field in `actions` subsection is `1011` and the `website_clicks` field is much higher (`2403`). Further more `like` + `link_clicks` + `comment` + `post` + `post_like` + `unlike` < `clicks` so that `checksum` fails.

Which field should I use if I want to know the true website click cpc? Could it be that the `website_clicks` takes into account social link clicks (In that case I would like to count them as well).

```
 {u'account_id': u'##########',
 u'actions': [{u'action_type': u'comment', u'value': 10},
              {u'action_type': u'like', u'value': 168},
              **{u'action_type': u'link_click', u'value': 1011},**
              {u'action_type': u'post', u'value': 51},
              {u'action_type': u'post_like', u'value': 477},
              {u'action_type': u'unlike', u'value': 1},
              {u'action_type': u'page_engagement', u'value': 1717},
              {u'action_type': u'post_engagement', u'value': 1549}],
 u'adgroup_id': u'#######',
 u'app_store_clicks': 0,
 u'campaign_group_id': u'#######',
 u'campaign_id': u'######',
 u'clicks': 2093,
 u'cost_per_action_type': [{u'action_type': u'comment', u'value': 22.791},
                           {u'action_type': u'like',
                            u'value': 1.3566071428571},
                           {u'action_type': u'link_click',
                            u'value': 0.22543026706231},
                           {u'action_type': u'post',
                            u'value': 4.4688235294118},
                           {u'action_type': u'post_like',
                            u'value': 0.47779874213836},
                           {u'action_type': u'unlike', u'value': 227.91},
                           {u'action_type': u'page_engagement',
                            u'value': 0.13273733255679},
                           {u'action_type': u'post_engagement',
                            u'value': 0.14713363460297}],
 u'cost_per_total_action': 0.13266006984866,
 u'cost_per_unique_click': 0.13688288288288,
 u'cpc': 0.10889154323937,
 u'cpm': 2.4488809137503,
 u'cpp': 3.2399351757079,
 u'ctr': 2.2489174465708,
 u'date_start': u'2015-09-03',
 u'date_stop': u'2015-09-08',
 u'deeplink_clicks': 0,
 u'frequency': 1.3230268395314,
 u'impressions': u'93067',
 u'reach': 70344,
 u'relevance_score': {u'negative_feedback': u'####',
                      u'positive_feedback': u'###',
                      u'score': ###,
                      u'status': u'OK'},
 u'social_clicks': 212,
 u'social_impressions': 8689,
 u'social_reach': 7382,
 u'spend': 227.91,
 u'total_action_value': 0,
 u'total_actions': 1718,
 u'total_unique_actions': 1645,
 u'unique_actions': [{u'action_type': u'comment', u'value': 10},
                     {u'action_type': u'like', u'value': 168},
                     {u'action_type': u'link_click', u'value': 963},
                     {u'action_type': u'post', u'value': 49},
                     {u'action_type': u'post_like', u'value': 454},
                     {u'action_type': u'unlike', u'value': 1},
                     {u'action_type': u'page_engagement', u'value': 1644},
                     {u'action_type': u'post_engagement', u'value': 1476}],
 u'unique_clicks': 1665,
 u'unique_ctr': 2.3669396110542,
 u'unique_impressions': 70344,
 u'unique_social_clicks': 167,
 u'unique_social_impressions': 7382,
 **u'website_clicks': 2403,**
 u'website_ctr': [{u'action_type': u'link_click', u'value': 1.0863141607659}]}
```

Thank you!